# got unsatisfied_authorization while using push_transaction to create new account

Tags: http

guys.I have been working on creating new account with push_transaction HTTP API recently.
**after signing transaction, got unsatisfied_authorization by push_transaction**.

> EOS ver: v1.0.6  local testnet
>
> Logic:
>    - unlock wallet
>    - create keys
>    - abi json to bin
>    - get creator pubkey, ref_block_num, ref_block_prefix
>    - sign transaction
>    - push transaction

---

## abi json to bin

#### req

`{
  'code': 'eosio', 
  'args': {
    'owner': {
      'keys': [
        {
          'key': 'EOS7dXxUx2UNiDaEJJgxfu8cWDLCcYuNLn5gRnDq52Ng2GLuHQnvw', 
          'weight': 1
        }
      ], 
      'accounts': [], 
      'waits': [], 
      'threshold': 1
    }, 
    'active': {
      'keys': [
        {
          'key': 'EOS7dXxUx2UNiDaEJJgxfu8cWDLCcYuNLn5gRnDq52Ng2GLuHQnvw', 
          'weight': 1
        }
      ], 
      'accounts': [], 
      'waits': [], 
      'threshold': 1
    }, 
    'creator': 'eosio.bios', 
    'name': 'acctest'
  }, 
  'authorization': [
    {
      'permission': 'active', 
      'actor': 'eosio.bios'
    }
  ], 
  'action': 'newaccount'
}`

#### resp

`{"binargs":"0000a6ee00ea3055000000206395113201000000010003692181a8dcac54a3b3c69dbac525f2c947234362d7bcf6989ced677066f3add70100000001000000010003692181a8dcac54a3b3c69dbac525f2c947234362d7bcf6989ced677066f3add701000000"}`

---

## get creator pubkey, ref_block_num, ref_block_prefix

- get creator pubkey by using get_account(eosio.bios)
- get ref_block_num by using get_info
- get ref_block_prefix by using get_block

---

## sign transaction

#### req

`[
  {
    'signatures': [],
    'expiration': '2018-06-26T06:00:00', 
    'scope': ['eosio', 'eosio.bios'], 
    'read_scope': [], 
    'ref_block_prefix': 3745072026, 
    'ref_block_num': 571009, 
    'actions': [
      {
        'data':
'0000a6ee00ea3055000000206395113201000000010003692181a8dcac54a3b3c69dbac525f2c947234362d7bcf6989ced677066f3add70100000001000000010003692181a8dcac54a3b3c69dbac525f2c947234362d7bcf6989ced677066f3add701000000', 
        'authorization': [
          {
            'permission': 'active', 
            'actor': 'eosio.bios'
          }
        ], 
        'account': 'eosio', 
        'name': 'newaccount'
      }
    ]
  }, 
  ['EOS7ZQbhsR8tPg8UCMu2x4LRoNWnjHxkvaY9m7cL7gsSRjqkdsuX3'],  # pubkey get from get account(eosio.bios)
  ''
]`

#### resp

`{
  "expiration":"2018-06-26T06:00:00",
  "ref_block_num":46721,
  "ref_block_prefix":3745072026,
  "max_net_usage_words":0,
  "max_cpu_usage_ms":0,
  "delay_sec":0,
  "context_free_actions":[],
  "actions":[
    {
      "account":"eosio",
      "name":"newaccount",
      "authorization":[{"actor":"eosio.bios","permission":"active"}],
      "data":
"0000a6ee00ea3055000000206395113201000000010003692181a8dcac54a3b3c69dbac525f2c947234362d7bcf6989ced677066f3add70100000001000000010003692181a8dcac54a3b3c69dbac525f2c947234362d7bcf6989ced677066f3add701000000"
    }
  ],
  "transaction_extensions":[],
  "signatures":["SIG_K1_KZK3QrdhCCDfppQHcc9k2w2VpQ6W4CvNP2h1q78uFdbquQSFnwD3GRaGKVkSiNTmA8Fgrwapwx3tgUEqJYCRo6Sb75KCt2"],
  "context_free_data":[]
}`

---

## push transaction

#### req

`{
  'context_free_data': [], 
  'transaction': {
    'expiration': '2018-06-26T06:00:00', 
    'delay_sec': 0, 
    'ref_block_num': 46721, 
    'ref_block_prefix': 3745072026, 
    'context_free_actions': [], 
    'actions': [
      {
        'data': '0000a6ee00ea3055000000206395113201000000010003692181a8dcac54a3b3c69dbac525f2c947234362d7bcf6989ced677066f3add70100000001000000010003692181a8dcac54a3b3c69dbac525f2c947234362d7bcf6989ced677066f3add701000000', 
        'authorization': [
          {
            'permission': 'active', 
            'actor': 'eosio.bios'
          }
        ], 
        'account': 'eosio', 
        'name': 'newaccount'
      }
    ]
  }, 
  'compression': 'none', 
  'signatures': ['SIG_K1_KZK3QrdhCCDfppQHcc9k2w2VpQ6W4CvNP2h1q78uFdbquQSFnwD3GRaGKVkSiNTmA8Fgrwapwx3tgUEqJYCRo6Sb75KCt2']
}`

#### resp

`{
  "code":500,
  "message":"Internal Service Error",
  "error": 
    {
      "code":3090003,
      "name":"unsatisfied_authorization",
      "what":"provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations",
      "details":[]
    }
}`

#### log on testnet

`1509695ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:405           handle_exception  ]FC Exception encountered while processing chain.push_transaction

1509695ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:406           handle_exception ]Exception 
Details: 3090003 unsatisfied_authorization: provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations transaction declares authority '{"actor":"eosio.bios","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms, provided permissions [], 
and provided keys["EOS7aBsGGoJTTgRDfLhgCgCCoKd2gQFM4XGW6mMGQVap8c2hqdoyK"]
{
  "auth": {
    "actor":"eosio.bios",
    "permission":"active"
  },
  "provided_delay":0,
  "provided_permissions":[],
  "provided_keys":["EOS7aBsGGoJTTgRDfLhgCgCCoKd2gQFM4XGW6mMGQVap8c2hqdoyK"],
  "delay_max_limit_ms":3888000000
}
thread-0  authorization_manager.cpp:409 check_authorization`

---

#### Questions

- How can i fix to provide permissions under signature?
- Why is the pubkey from the testnet log not identical to any pubkey requested?
- How to make this whole thing work?

*Appreciate your help!!!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually encounter this error when I forget to set the Chain ID on the signing request.  The chain ID is returned from the `get_info` RPC call and is set as the last parameter on the signing request, right after the list of public keys.

Comment: yes!that's the key.It it working after adding chain id.thank u very much!